# Anchor Tag (hover) and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The anchor tag below works.  However, my question is, 'how can the anchor tag force the cursor to change its appearance (like most links do) when hovering over it?'

```
<a onclick="doSomethingh(1)">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it an HREF attribute, then disable the action when you click on the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomethingh(1);return false;">Click Me</a>
```

---

Note, however, that it's best not to put your Javascript inline.  Use event listeners (`addEventListener`/`attachEvent`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style of the cursor either inline or in a separate CSS rule.

`<a onclick="doSomethingh(1)" style="cursor: pointer">Click Me</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it an href.

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomethingh(1)">Click Me</a>
```

There are a couple of options here (the best of which is to actually put your onclick somewhere else), but this should suffice for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

using css

```
a {
cursor: hand; /* show the hand like most browsers do for links */
}
```

Or, give the anchor a destination (href="#") and most(tm) browsers will do it for you

more info about cursor support: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using either JavaScript or CSS.

CSS:

```
a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

JavaScript:

```
document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

CSS would be the best practices way.